# How to remove JDK 7 and install JDK 8 in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, java

JDK 7 is already installed in Linux Mint by default. I want to remove it and to install JDK 8 instead. I youtubed and i found a tutorial. I followed it. What i did was,
first i downloaded JDK from [http://www.oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). after that,

```
tar -zxvf jdk1.8*
mv jdk1.8* /usr/lib/java/
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javaws" 1
```

Also i appended bellow codes to `/etc/profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_65
set PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export PATH
```

After a reboot, an error was displayed something related to environment variables that i appended to `/etc/profile`.

So i removed those commands from the `/etc/profile` and tried  codes in a terminal. No errors, but `java -version` still gives the old version of Java.

Comment: Does it work better if you use the `jdk1.8...` directory as `JAVA_HOME`? (First line of your `/etc/profile` snippet.)

Comment: What you get running this comand? 

    `$ sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TbLg9Yb.png 
this was the out put, sir.

Comment: @MickyInTheSky can you please check top comment

Answer (score 3):

You have to run this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select the proper number of java 8 (es. 1).

Then the command:

```
java -version
```

should return the java version you wanted